# Scrollable TableLayout & Column Headers

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, tablelayout

I am trying to create a basic datasheet in my application using a TableLayout. The first row contains the titles of each column. Every row thereafter is data. I would like the data to be scrollable while keeping the first *title row* visible (i.e. the first row would not scroll with the rest).

I have tried something like the following (unsuccessfully):

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <!-- The headers -->
    <TextView android:text="Header #1"/>
    <TextView android:text="Header #2"/>
    <TextView android:text="Header #3"/>
  </TableRow>

  <ScrollView>
    <!--The rest of the data -->
    <TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
</TableLayout>
```

This causes the program to crash. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because you can only have `TableRow`s as direct descendants in a `TableLayout`.

What you probably want to use is a `ListView` and a 'header' above it.

Example (not complete):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/header1"
      android:layout_weight="1"
   />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/header2"
      android:layout_weight="1"
   />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/header3"
      android:layout_weight="1"
   />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
...
/>
```

The key is the `layout_weight="1"` and the `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` that will give you 3 views of equal size. You'll then need to create an `Adapter` and in your custom layout provided by the `Adapter` do the same thing for the child views. You might have to fiddle slightly with the padding/margins for them to line up horizontally exactly.

Comment: I have tried something similar to this. Will give it another shot in the morning and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Okay, it seems I've managed to work something out. One more question: is there a way to manipulate 'layout_weight' so that one of the columns is a bit wider than the others? (maybe 1.25x wider than the other columns would do the job).

Comment: Setting the layout_weight to a lower value (such as .75) did the trick. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to have tablerow as direct descendant, it crashes because scrollview accepts one child only. put another tablelayout in scrollview and put rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using in the `RelativeLayout` both `ScrollView` and `TableLayout` aligned to the top, and populating both `TableLayouts` with the same first Row can make a trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tabscrvie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/headergridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tabscrvie"
            >
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```